# Image set to 100% but still margin at the bottom

Tags: css, image, background-image

I want to have an image that completely covers a div (without content). I tried to do it with background-image and background-size but since there is no content, it doesn't work. I also don't want to set a height because then the image gets stretched (I want it to be responsive). So I tried to fix it with putting the image inside the div and setting it to width:100% and height:100%. It does the trick (image stretches according to the div) but I still have a small margin at the bottom of the img  which I can't seem to get deleted. I set all margins and paddings to 0px but still no result (even border-sizing is set to border-box). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I haven't set a height so, seeing other questions, maybe the div (wrapper-1) doesn't have a setting point to adapt to? Is that the right way to put an image to a div without content? Thx in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="row col-12  wrapper-1"><img src="wrapper.jpg" alt="Wrapper" 
width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper-1 {
 height: auto;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 }
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to give `margin:0;` to the body or html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a `display: block` to the `img` tag will solve it.

Comment: I had sae issue and this display: block solved it. However I don't understand why it wasn't working with default inline. Any reason why? Or any resource I read to find about it?